# What's the point of adding a disclaimer in a PDF file to respect Adobe's licensing policy when editing the PDF?

Tags: licensing

I see that the [International Organization for Standardization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Organization_for_Standardization) has the following disclaimer in some of its standards (example: https://web.archive.org/web/20200503214211/https://people.engr.ncsu.edu/jwilson/files/mathsigns):

[image]

> PDF disclaimer: This PDF file may contain embedded typefaces. In accordance with Adobe's licensing policy, this file may be printed or viewed but shall not be edited unless the typefaces which are embedded are licensed to and installed on the computer performing the editing. In downloading this file, parties accept therein the responsibility of not infringing Adobe's licensing policy. The ISO Central Secretariat accepts no liability in this area.

What's the point of adding a disclaimer in a PDF file to respect Adobe's licensing policy when editing the PDF? I would have guessed that even if ISO didn't have this disclaimer the same licensing policies would apply.